# Rendering asynchronous data fetching in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, next.js, react-hooks

```
export default async function Page() {
  const endpoint = `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RPC_URL}`;
  const cmId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CANDY_MACHINE_ID? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CANDY_MACHINE_ID : '';

let umi: Umi = createUmi(endpoint)
.use(mplTokenMetadata())
.use(mplCandyMachine());

const [nfts, setNfts] = useState<NFT[]>([]);
const [uris, setUris] = useState<string[]>([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
  const getNFTs = async () => {
    await fetchCandyMachine(umi, publicKey(cmId))
      .then(cm => cm.items)
      .then(items => items.map(item => setUris(prevUris => [...prevUris, item.uri])));

    for (const uri of uris) {
      await fetch(uri)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          let nft = {
            name: json.name,
            symbol: json.symbol,
            description: json.description,
            image: json.image
          }
          setNfts(prevNfts => [...prevNfts, nft]);
        })
    }

  }

  getNFTs()
  .then(e => setLoading(false));
}, []);

return(
  <div>
  <div>
  <Link href='/'>Home</Link>
  </div>
  {loading && 
   <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  {!loading && nfts.map((nft, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    <Image src={nft.image} alt={nft.name} width={500} height={300} />
  </div>
))}
  </div>
)

  }
```

Hello, I've written this piece of code that should fetch all the nfts metadata associated with the uris and after that rendering the images associated with the nfts... The problem is that the page remains stuck in the Loading... component bc the data fetching is never resolved. How can I ensure that useEffect resolves?

I tried to enclose all the data fetching into an async function defined inside the useEffect hook. I want the rendering to dynamically change on the value of isLoading, but this variable remains stuck on true

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getNFTs = async () => {
    const candyMachine = await fetchCandyMachine(umi, publicKey(cmId));
    const itemUris = candyMachine.items.map(item => item.uri);
    const metadataPromises = itemUris.map(uri => fetch(uri).then(response => response.json()));
    const metadata = await Promise.all(metadataPromises);
    const nfts = metadata.map(json => ({
      name: json.name,
      symbol: json.symbol,
      description: json.description,
      image: json.image
    }));
    setNfts(nfts);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  getNFTs();
}, []);
```

hope this one helps you